# How to write a generic findMax() method using collections.max()?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am trying to create a generic method findMax(List list), that takes in either List of LocalDate or List of Date type, and return the maximum value in the list.

Collections.max(List LocalDate) and Collections.max(List Date) both works perfectly fine, but I don't know how to make it to return the correct type back.

Don't really understand how comparator works in Java.

Below is my attempt

```
static List<LocalDate> localDateList = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
static List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();

private <T> T findMax(List<T> list) {
    return Collections.max(list);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, SQLException, JsonProcessingException {

    localDateList.add(new Date(11 * 86400000).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    localDateList.add(new Date(22 * 86400000).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    localDateList.add(new Date(3 * 86400000).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    localDateList.add(new Date(14 * 86400000).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    localDateList.add(new Date(65 * 86400000).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());

    dateList.add(new Date(11 * 86400000));
    dateList.add(new Date(22 * 86400000));
    dateList.add(new Date(3 * 86400000));
    dateList.add(new Date(14 * 86400000));
    dateList.add(new Date(65 * 86400000));

    System.out.println(Collections.max(localDateList));
    System.out.println(Collections.max(dateList));

    System.out.println(findMax(localDateList));
    System.out.println(findMax(dateList));

}
```

**EDITED:**
Got it to work by changing from

```
private <T> T findMax(List<T> list) {
    return Collections.max(list);
}
```

to

```
private <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T findMax(List<T> list) {
    return Collections.max(list);
}
```

Comment: `Collections.max` already return the "correct" type back. For example, `String s = Collections.max(yourListOfString)` will compile.

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code? Why do you try to wrap Collections.max() into a method doing exactly the same thing? And if you really want to, why don't you use the exact same generic types as Collections.max()?

Comment: It tells you that it's an object because of type erasure. Generic types are only known by the compiler at compile time and are only relevant then. They are there to avoid unsafe casts as much as possible.

Comment: @OuYe By the way, the java.time classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. Not intended to be mixed. Stick with java.time. Use the old classes only when required for working with old code not yet updated to java.time types.

Comment: You would have to change the generic type of your `findMax` method from `<T>` to `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>` if you want your  `findMax` method to compile, but I don't see the point.

Comment: my problem is it wouldn't compile, although collection.max() return the correct type when feed in the list, but it wouldn't compile. But <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> to the method fixed the compiling problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Collections.max()`

No need to write your `findMax` method. The `Collections.max` already does that for you.

```
List<LocalDate> localDates = new ArrayList<> ( 3 );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
localDates.add ( today );
localDates.add ( today.plusDays ( 2 ) );
localDates.add ( today.minusDays ( 4 ) );

LocalDate max = Collections.max ( localDates );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDates: " + localDates + " | max: " + max );
```

> localDates: [2016-08-18, 2016-08-20, 2016-08-14] | max: 2016-08-20

## Comparing

Any class implementing the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface must implement a [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method. That method must return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than another object of the same type.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class has this `compareTo` method implemented.

The [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) method loops the elements of a collection such as a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and calls each object’s `compareTo` method. All that is done on your behalf, to relieve you of the chore of writing such code.

## Generics

Comments suggest the Question was really more about [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) that about comparing.

Here is an example of implementing your `findMax` method. I followed the example of the [`Collections.max` source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java) for Java 8 in the OpenJDK project.

As I said above, there is no productive use for merely wrapping the call to `Collections.max`. But it does make a nice experimental example of using generics.

```
public <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T findMax ( Collection<? extends T> coll ) {
    T maximum = Collections.max ( coll );
    return maximum;
}
```

Calling that method and passing the `localDates` collection seen above.

```
System.out.println ( "findMax: " + this.findMax ( localDates ) );
```

Comment: Do you have any clue why they use `Object & Comparable` ? As per my understanding, everything being an object, `T extends Comparable` would directly compile. I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Ah I get it, it is to force the type to be `Object` under erasure in order to maintain compatibility with pre-generics API.